# Font Awesome icons don't appear correctly in Google Chrome version 49.0.2623.112

Tags: google-chrome, windows-xp, browser

[image: Part of screen where the error occurs]

I cannot see Font Awesome icons in Google Chrome (version 49.0.2623.112). I encounter the same issue in the main site, fontawesome.com.

How can I solve this?

Operating system: Windows XP

Comment: You are using an operating system whose support ended in 2014, with a browser that was released in 2016. What are you expecting?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on using extremely outdated software.

Comment: @slhck Are questions about using outdated software off-topic in SU? Can't that be the answer to the question? (That OP is using an outdated browser.)

Comment: @galacticninja Not generally – there are even Windows 3.11 questions here, but if it's so obvious that there will not be a solution because the OP is using an unsupported OS or software, then we'd rather close the question, as it's not going to be of much use to anyone. Of course a valid answer could be: Get a newer browser/OS.

Comment: Basically, getting a newer OS will probably solve the problem. If you won't go to a newer version of Windows you should go to some Linux variant. Running Windows XP on a computer connected to the internet today means you are part of a serious problem, and you are being that problem on purpose, despite easy and superior alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a very old, outdated browser. [Google has ended Chrome’s support for Windows XP back in April 2016.](https://chrome.googleblog.com/2015/11/updates-to-chrome-platform-support.html)

I checked fontawesome.com with the latest version of Chrome, and it shows up fine. The best solution is to upgrade to Windows 7 or newer versions of Windows, which are still compatible with Chrome. Then, update Chrome to the latest version. This ensures you have an updated, secure browser.

If you can’t upgrade Windows XP, you need to use a more updated browser than your version of Chrome that still works for Windows XP:

- [One-Core-API binaries](https://github.com/Skulltrail192/One-Core-API-Binaries) - This lets Windows XP users run some software that are not supported in Windows XP anymore, such as Chrome up to version 102, Opera up to version 39, Firefox up to version 54, and others.
- [Opera 36](https://get.opera.com/pub/opera-winxpvista/) - You can still [download it from the official site](https://get.opera.com/pub/opera-winxpvista/), and it still supports Windows XP, according to an [official blog post](https://blogs.opera.com/news/2016/04/chrome-alternative-opera-for-windows-xp-vista/).
- [Firefox 52.9.0esr](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/52.9.0esr/) (released June 2018) - [the last supported Firefox version for Windows XP and Windows Vista](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/end-support-windows-xp-and-vista)